# Getting gray colour in the left and right of my Carousel Slider . How to remove gray colour?

Tags: javascript, html, css

1. I had Created Carousel effect , of images but it seems like it had
   gray shaded colour in that in its left and rifht End poit.
           I want to remove that but i dont know how to remove it .
       Getting gray colour in the left and right of my Carousel Slider . 
       How to remove gray colour ?
       I had provided you a Screen shot of that , you can easily go through that.
           Below is my Code .

```js
 // Instantiate the Bootstrap carousel
$('.multi-item-carousel').carousel({
  interval: false
});

// for every slide in carousel, copy the next slide's item in the slide.
// Do the same for the next, next item.
$('.multi-item-carousel .item').each(function(){
  var next = $(this).next();
  if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
  }
  next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

  if (next.next().length>0) {
    next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  } else {
    $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  }
});
```

```css
   .multi-item-carousel{
  .carousel-inner{
    > .item{
      transition:  ease-in-out left;
    }
    .active{
      &.left{
        left:-33%;
      }
      &.right{
        left:33%;
      }
    }
    .next{
      left: 33%;
    }
    .prev{
      left: -33%;
    }
    @media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d) {
      > .item{
        // use your favourite prefixer here
        transition: 500ms ease-in-out left;
        transition: 500ms ease-in-out all;
        backface-visibility: visible;
        transform: none!important;
      }
    }
  }
  .carouse-control{
    &.left, &.right{
      background-image: none;
    }
  }
}

// non-related styling:
body{
  background: #333;
  color: #ddd;
}
h1{
  color: white;
  font-size: 2.25em;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>






</head>
<body>


<div class="container">
  <h1>Use Bootstrap's carousel to show multiple items per slide.</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="carousel slide multi-item-carousel" id="theCarousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/f44336/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/e91e63/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/9c27b0/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/673ab7/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/4caf50/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/8bc34a/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <!-- add  more items here -->
          <!-- Example item start:  -->

          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/8bc34a/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>

          <!--  Example item end -->
        </div>
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
Here is the Screen Shot of that :-
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to change both classes:

```
.carousel-control.left,
.carousel-control.right {
  background: transparent;
}
```

It has a default value of:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to right,rgba(0,0,0,.5) 0,rgba(0,0,0,.0001) 100%);
```

**UPDATE**
Both arrows use the Bootstrap icons, so you'll have to change both classes:

```
.glyphicon.glyphicon-chevron-left,
.glyphicon.glyphicon-chevron-right {
  color: red; //Example
}
```

Those classes are Bootstrap standard classes, if you have a global style file, this will change all occurrences of both classes, thus changing all the color of all the other arrows.

Comment: and how to give some other color to the left and right arrow in that carousel .?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `background-image: none !important;` on your slide? It will remove the black semi-transparent image you mean.

You have to apply this style to the `.carousel-control.left` & `.carousel-control.right` classes.

If you have your own stylesheet just add these two stylings like so:

```
.carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right {
    background-image:none;
}
```

Comment: and how to give some other color to the left and right arrow in that carousel .?

Answer (score 0):

You only have to override the default behavior:
.carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right{background: none !important;}

You can modify it from bootstrap and avoid the needing to use !important statement.

```css
.multi-item-carousel{
  .carousel-inner{
    > .item{
      transition:  ease-in-out left;
    }
    .active{
      &.left{
        left:-33%;
      }
      &.right{
        left:33%;
      }
    }
    .next{
      left: 33%;
    }
    .prev{
      left: -33%;
    }
    @media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d) {
      > .item{
        // use your favourite prefixer here
        transition: 500ms ease-in-out left;
        transition: 500ms ease-in-out all;
        backface-visibility: visible;
        transform: none!important;
      }
    }
  }
  .carouse-control{
    &.left, &.right{
      background-image: none;
    }
  }
}

// non-related styling:
body{
  background: #333;
  color: #ddd;
}
h1{
  color: white;
  font-size: 2.25em;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

.carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right{background: none !important;}
```

```html
<html>
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Instantiate the Bootstrap carousel
$('.multi-item-carousel').carousel({
  interval: false
});

// for every slide in carousel, copy the next slide's item in the slide.
// Do the same for the next, next item.
$('.multi-item-carousel .item').each(function(){
  var next = $(this).next();
  if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
  }
  next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

  if (next.next().length>0) {
    next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  } else {
    $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  }
});


</script>

</head>
<body>


<div class="container">
  <h1>Use Bootstrap's carousel to show multiple items per slide.</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="carousel slide multi-item-carousel" id="theCarousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/f44336/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/e91e63/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/9c27b0/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/673ab7/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/4caf50/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/8bc34a/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <!-- add  more items here -->
          <!-- Example item start:  -->

          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/8bc34a/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>

          <!--  Example item end -->
        </div>
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: and how to give some other color to the left and right arrow in that carousel .?

Comment: you're welcome! i suggest you to inspect elements and use chrome (or other) to test changes on it. then you only need to apply the changes and test.

Answer (score 0):

I will serach first the "wrong" code, just right-clic the carrousel, then 
inspect or inspect element (may be different in your browser), and try to find the element causing the mess. Maybe the solution is a "*margin:0;*", maybe is a "*background: transparent;*" or maybe the "*background-image:none;*" but you first have to know who is guilty and why and we can't check it from a screenshot or from your code because the mistake comes clearly from one of the libreries you use.

Comment: and how to give some other color to the left and right arrow in that carousel .?

Comment: background-image:none; background-color:_your-color_; but you have to know the element with the grey background first. If you can't find it write your url and I will find it for you.